# How can I add a checkbox to each element in the list and to be able to control it through state in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just finished an introductory course on React and now I am trying to make a react app where the user can add and remove items from a todo list. My trouble is when I try and add a checkbox to my program. I have tried to create a state that keeps track of the list items but I cant seem to figure out how to link the state to the items itself. Any tips on how I can add check boxes to my todo items would be greatly appreciated. Here is my App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react"
import Todoitems from "./Todoitems"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      numberOfItems: 0,
      limitReached: false
    }

    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
  }

  addItem = (e) => {
    if (this.state.numberOfItems < 10){
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {numberOfItems: prevState.numberOfItems + 1}
      })
        if (this._inputElement !== "") {
          let newItem = {
            text: this._inputElement.value,
            key: Date.now()
          }
          
            this.setState(prevState => {
              return {
                items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)
              };
            });
          
          this._inputElement.value  = "";
        }
        console.log(this.state.items);
        console.log(this.state.numberOfItems);
    
        
    } else {
      this.setState({
       limitReached: true
      })
    }
    console.log(this.state.limitReached)
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Todoitems entries = {this.state.items}/>
        <form onSubmit = {this.addItem}>
          <input ref = {(a) => this._inputElement = a} placeholder = "enter task"></input>
          {this.state.limitReached === false? <button type = "submit">Add</button>: <p>Maximum amount of items added</p>}
            
          
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you have a checkbox in your TodoItem.

```html
// todoItem.jsx

<input type='checkbox' checked={props.entry.checked} value={props.entry.checked}  onChange={(e) => props.handleEntryCheck(e.value, props.index)} />
```

And you are looping through entries to show them like this:

```js
// TodoItems.jsx

{
entries.map((entry, index) => <TodoItem index={index} entry={entry} handleEntryCheck={props.handleEntryCheck} /> )
}
```

In your `App.jsx` you can define `handleEntryCheck` like this:

```
const handleEntryCheck = (checked, index) => {
 state.items[index].checked = checked
 this.setState({
       items: state.items.slice()
      })
}
```

Later you can find out which items are selected:

```
const getSelectedItems = () => {
 return state.items.filter(item => item.checked)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add state in `newItem` variable in `addItem` function like `clicked` below:

```js
let newItem = {
            text: this._inputElement.value,
            key: Date.now(),
            clicked: false
          }
```

And add `input` tag in `TodoItems` component's mapping function inside for checkbox with `onChange` event having function like below :

```js
<input type="checkbox" id={data.key} onChange = {(e) => {
     let newItem = {
            text: this.state.item[key].text,
            key: this.state.item[key].key,
            clicked: e.target.value
          }
     let newItems = this.state.items.splice(e.target.id, 1, newItem);

  this.setState({
    items: newItems
})
 }} />
```

It's not easy to explain without code executor so I could give better advice if you give an URL of [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io).